how to create a BottomNavigationBar with a curved notch in flutter
I'm trying to create a curved notch in my bottomNavBar like the following image: Desired Shape
I've tried to use the CircularNotchedRectangle shape but i didn't get the same shape, i tried to use a custom paint with quadraticBezier but this is the best i've got: Custom Paint I don't have a good knowledge in customPainter or canvas so I'd appreciate if you send a good resource to learn from or give a hint on what i should try to create the shape, if there's a package to solve this issue i'd be really grateful if you share it. i searched for packages but didn't find any.

try this

Try to use flutter's package animated_bottom_navigation_bar.

BottomAppBar will shape into this if you add a FloatingActionButton. Create a custom bottom navbar widget with BottomAppBar as the base. You might need to handle different color of selected icon & label by yourself, but the logic should be simple.

check https://gist.github.com/pskink/adf730167a48b750a81f1dd197309312 - it has "dynamic #1" sample and is implemented in _MorphingButton1 class - this is how it looks like: https://pasteboard.co/yAExFpPDPy8D.webp - all you need to do is to change it from vertical layout into horizontal layout

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Check This Article : https://medium.com/@akhil-ge0rge/how-to-create-a-notched-bottom-navigation-bar-flutter-39b571afd570
